# Reshaping RAID-1 to RAID-5 hangs forever

Tags: linux, debian, raid, raid-1, raid-5

I have a problem with reshaping RAID level 1 to RAID level 5: it's been hanging at 41% for a few days now.

Some background (verbose, since I don't know will end up being relevant; apologies).

The device in question is a GNUBee NAS running Debian 9.

```
$ uname -a
Linux gnubee-n1.gnubee 4.4.87-gnu #0 SMP Wed Nov 22 13:06:13 2017 mips GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)
Release:    9.11
Codename:   stretch
```

I had 2 2TB drives in a RAID level 1. I then got 2 more 5TB drives, that I wanted to add to the array. After reading some guides, I discovered that I could "upgrade" from RAID level 1 to RAID level 5, because of specifically going from 2 drives to more than 2. I decided to go for it.

I installed the new drives, wiped them, reformatted them as ext4, and mounted them. I backed up all the data on the original drives, and just to be sure I checked the original RAID array's health.

```
/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray /dev/md0
```

All fine.

Then I tried to switch to RAID 5.

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=5
```

However, I got an error that the block size wasn't a multiple of 4K.

After some more research, I figured out that I needed to shrink my existing RAID array size to be a multiple of 4K (much like the error suggested).

```
resize2fs /dev/md0 1.5TB
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=1874604032
```

This worked without error.

I switched the RAID level to 5.

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=5 --backup-file=/root/grow_md0.bak
```

Again, no errors, and I confirmed that the new RAID level was 5.

Then I added the 2 new drives to the array, and grew it to 4 drives.

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mdadm --grow --raid-devices=4 --backup-file=/root/grow_md0.bak /dev/md0
```

This once again worked without error. I knew this process would take a long time, a day or two maybe, so I checked back in a bit, and found the reshaping percentage increasing. Satisfied, I let the machine do it's thing for a day.

When I checked back the reshaping was at 41%. I didn't think much of it; maybe it was going a little slow, but I had never added drives to an array before, so what did I know?

I checked back the next day, and again 41%. And the day after that. I started to suspect something was up. (Sherlock hat)

```
$ mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 26 21:54:30 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 1874604032 (1787.76 GiB 1919.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1874604032 (1787.76 GiB 1919.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Apr  4 12:17:09 2020
          State : clean, reshaping
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

 Reshape Status : 41% complete
  Delta Devices : 2, (2->4)

           Name : libreCMC:0
           UUID : c04d31c3:6579cf28:acb7b965:2d4c5e1d
         Events : 5498

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       3       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
       2       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
```

I don't have any idea what might be wrong, or where to start digging, so any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Repeated calls to `/proc/mdstat` output the following.

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sde[3] sdd[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      1874604032 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [========>............]  reshape = 41.2% (773695612/1874604032) finish=11211
552.6min speed=1K/sec

unused devices: <none>

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sde[3] sdd[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      1874604032 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [========>............]  reshape = 41.2% (773695612/1874604032) finish=11211
594.4min speed=1K/sec

unused devices: <none>

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sde[3] sdd[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      1874604032 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [========>............]  reshape = 41.2% (773695612/1874604032) finish=11212
178.5min speed=1K/sec

unused devices: <none>

# After 2 hours

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sde[3] sdd[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      1874604032 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [========>............]  reshape = 41.2% (773695612/1874604032) finish=11420355.0min speed=1K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Output of `sysctl dev.raid.speed_limit_min`

```
dev.raid.speed_limit_min = 10000
```

Comment: What do (repeated) iterations of cat /proc/mdstat show?

Comment: Added the output to cat /proc/mdstat to my question. Thanks @davidgo

Comment: Can you provide 1 more output of cat /proc/mdstat now (after some time)?  Also, are there any disk related error messages in /var/log/?????  and how busy heavily used is the system? I confess this looks a bit weird (time to complete fluctuating but out if sync blocks not)

Comment: Also, what is the output of "sysctl dev.raid.speed_limit_min"? This should tell us the minimum rebuild speed - maybe it needs to be increased.

Comment: Thanks again @davidgo. I added the output from both another /proc/mdstat (after 2 hours) and the raid speed limit to the question.

Comment: Weird. All I can conclude us that your rebuild has stopped (unsynced blocks remain the same). I'm speculating wildly, without evidence - I wonder if the underlying problem is the addition of5tb disks?  The math of 41% would seem consistent with this?

Comment: Huh, perhaps. Is there a way to safely restart the reshape? Would that even be wise?

Comment: I can't answer you.  I've not done anything with RAID5 (but lots with RAID1), and I consider block operations of this kind to be high risk.  The theory is that you can reboot the computer and the RAID will continue to build/work, but I'm not in a position to advise.  I would advise that if you do find a way to restart from scratch you don't go RAID5 - Sizewise you are at (arguably over) the limit of where RAID5 can provide adequate protection.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @davidgo. That's good to know about RAID 5 maybe not being appropriate for a disk this large. I think I'll re-do the array as a RAID 1.

Comment: do you mean RAID10?  If you are going RAID1 - and its not a stupid idea - I'd suggest you look at RAID 1 in pairs, then use LVM to enlist the resulting raid arrays as physical volumes and then bond those physical volumes into volume groups, which could give you more flexibility when it comes to resizing / manipulating volumes in the future.  A useful read about RAID5 is https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/